# how to target Andoid 10 email client (on Huawei)

Tags: android, huawei-developers

I've tried following targetting css, but it doesn't work:

```
  .edo-email-view .foo, body[data-outlook-cycle] .hide-for-large {
        display: none !important;
    }

    @media screen and (pointer) {
        .foo .hide-for-large {
            display: none !important;
        }
    }

    _:-webkit-full-screen,
    :root .foo .hide-for-large {
        display: none !important;
    }
```